# Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3::removeMessage doesn't work

Tags: php, zend-framework, pop3

I have a e-mail driver. It get a list of e-mail accounts and receive and store messages, it works fine. But the messages deletion, at last line, doesn't works. Thats a part of code:

```
$arrPop3Config['host'] = $arrEmailconfiguracao['strPOPHost'];
$arrPop3Config['port'] = $arrEmailconfiguracao['intPOPPorta'];
$arrPop3Config['user'] = $arrEmailconfiguracao['strPOPUsuario'];
$arrPop3Config['password'] = $arrEmailconfiguracao['strPOPSenha'];
if($arrEmailconfiguracao['intAuth'] == '1') {
    $arrPop3Config['ssl'] = 'SSL';
} else if($arrEmailconfiguracao['intAuth'] == '2') {
    $arrPop3Config['ssl'] = 'TLS';
}

$objMail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3($arrPop3Config);

foreach($objMail as $intMensagemNum => $objMensagem) {

    $strMensagemUniqueId = $objMail->getUniqueId($intMensagemNum);
    $arrHeader = $objMensagem->getHeaders();
    $strRemetente = $objMensagem->getHeader('from', 'string');
    preg_match_all("/(.*)?<(.*)?>/", $strRemetente, $arrRemetente);
    $strRemetenteNome = $arrRemetente[1][0];
    $strRemetenteEmail = $arrRemetente[2][0];
    $strTitulo = $objMensagem->getHeader('subject', 'string');
    $objMensagemPart = $objMensagem;
    while ($objMensagemPart->isMultipart()) {
        $objMensagemPart = $objMensagem->getPart(1);
    }
    $strCorpo = $objMensagemPart->getContent();

    $objDb->call(
        'emailClienteRecebe'
        ,array(
            'intEmailconfiguracao' => $arrEmailconfiguracao['intId']
            ,'strMensagemUniqueId' => $strMensagemUniqueId
            ,'strRemetenteNome' => $strRemetenteNome
            ,'strRemetenteEmail' => $strRemetenteEmail
            ,'strHeaders' => serialize($arrHeader)
            ,'strTitulo' => $strTitulo
            ,'strCorpo' => $strCorpo
        )
    );


    $objMail->removeMessage($strMensagemUniqueId);
```

Php client return this message:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'last request failed' in /var/www/maru/Maru/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Pop3.php:189
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/maru/Maru/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Pop3.php(221): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Pop3->readResponse(false)
#1 /var/www/maru/Maru/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Pop3.php(457): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Pop3->request('DELE GmailId12d...')
#2 /var/www/maru/Maru/Zend/Mail/Storage/Pop3.php(227): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Pop3->delete('GmailId12de8345...')
#3 /var/www/maru/drivers/recebe-emails/driver.php(82): Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3->removeMessage('GmailId12de8345...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/maru/Maru/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Pop3.php on line 189
```

Apparently the pop command "DELE GmailId1283038051edcc6e" is the problem. However, using a common e-mail client, like mozilla thunderbird, i've monitorated sent commands e the same command works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: By default POP3 deletes messages on the server once they are downloaded... could this be part of the issue?

Comment: I am receiving and deleting messages, but deleting doesn't work and my script receive the same messages.

Comment: Poke. Are the answer given by me not good enough? Could you comment on it or at least show some progress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know nothing about the Zend Pop3 client, only by looking at the online documentation.

The [POP3 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939#page-8) has a DELE command, taking a message number. You are supplying a string!
Therefore the server of course does not know what to do. The Zend POP3 method even states that the id supplied has to be of integer type in the [removeMessage documentation](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/zf/Mail/Storage/Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3.class.html#det_methods_removeMessage).

If you look at the [getNumberByUniqueId documentation](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/zf/Mail/Storage/Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3.class.html#det_methods_getNumberByUniqueId), you will see that you should translate the unique ID to a message number before calling removeMessage.

Therefore, to fix your problem, you should replace your last line with:

```
$objMail->removeMessage($objMail->getNumberByUniqueId($strMensagemUniqueId));
```

And then I think everything will be fine.